# Punctuation (vocative comma)

Tags: grammar, punctuation

Would the phrase read "Run, Joey, run!"...or does the placement of the vocative commas make absolutely no sense?

Answer (score 1):

One of the most famous lines in English movies is from Forrest Gump:

> Run, Forrest! Run!

(source: [IMDb](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109830/quotes?item=qt0373725))

but I don't think it's a problem (and I have often seen it written so) to write it as a single sentence:

> Run, Forrest, run!

(Forrest is, like Joey, a given name).